# Probability with 5 couples

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 5 couples. We need to make a team with 4 people. What is the probability that only one person from couple will be taken in the team?

I know that to take 4 people we can in $C^4_{10}=210$ ways. But I don't know how many ways we can choose 4 people that in the team will be no coples. Can somebody help me?

Comment: 'one person from couple' is a bit vague ... do you mean one person from each couple? But that's impossible given that there are 5 couples but only 4 team members ... ... maybe you mean that there is no couple for which both members end up on the team?

Answer (score 1):

First select the $4$ couples (out of $5$) that will provide in a team member.

Then out of each of the $4$ selected couples select one person.

There are $\binom54\binom21^4$ possibilities for this, leading to probability:$$\frac{\binom54\binom21^4}{\binom{10}4}$$

Comment: I don’t think your solution is right. You chose 5 people for team

Comment: I did not. First $4$ couples are chosen out of $5$ couples. That gives  $5$ possibilities. After that one person is chosen from each of the $4$ selected couples. So we end up with a team of $4$ persons.